AWS Amplify Gen 2: Accidentally Deleted API Key in AWS Console: Restoring Access for App and CD Pipeline
I accidentally deleted my API Key in the AWS Console. My previous token expired, and generating a new one automatically deleted the old token, which my app and CD pipeline still rely on. As a result, deployments are failing. I am in need of a solution to update my app and pipeline to use the new API key.
